# How frequent can a ProActive bot send message to a user?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am using BotFramework v4 with C#. I haven't yet tried making a proactive bot. But i am planning to do a Reminder-like feature. The user can make the bot remind him/her of something. So my question is can the bot remind a user everyday, everyweek or everymonth? Can you specify specific day or hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bot Framework SDK does not limit how many proactive messages can be sent; however, some channels do throttle messages from bots in general. As long as you not spamming a user, it should be fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you sir how does proactive works? will you manually send a message to a user? or is it possible to do a reminder-like feature that remind a user something the user input with a specific date and time?